# ggplot How to scatter plot one column and line plot another

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot in R from a data frame with several columns and I'd like to have ggplot plot one of the columns as points, and the other several as lines of different colors.

I can find examples about how to make each of these plots separately, but I can't seem to find the command to combine the plots...

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(points.x = c(1:10), points.y = c(1:10),
 lines.x = c(10:1), lines.y = c(1:10))

ggplot(dat, aes(points.x, points.y)) + geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(lines.x,lines.y))
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to plot several different columns as lines of different colors, use the `melt` function from the `reshape2` package.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=rnorm(10), C=rnorm(10), D=rnorm(10))
melted <- melt(df, id="A")

ggplot(melted[melted$variable!="B",], aes(A, value, color=variable)) + geom_line() + 
    geom_point(data=melted[melted$variable=="B",])
```